# Graphing of $y= \csc(x)+ \cot(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What's the graph or table of values of $y=\csc(x) + \cot(x)$? I have already solved and graphed the values of $\csc(x)$ and $\cot(x)$.

Comment: Since you look for table of values, I recommend you [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1ypBOqyzUE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

graph of $$\csc { \left( x \right)  } +\cot { \left( x \right)  } $$

Comment: Do you have a table of values of this one?

Comment: Do you want to find graph or how to find graph?

Comment: You have already given the graph but I also want to know how to find the graph.

Comment: $\frac { 1+\cos { x }  }{ \sin { x }  } =\cot { \frac { x }{ 2 }  } $ you should just find graph of cotx/2 it is not hard i guess

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

First write $$f(x)=\csc(x)+\cot(x)=\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}$$
Now find the asymptotes, zeros and limiting behaviour around the asymptotes.

Comment: Or just simply use $1+\cos x=2\cos^2\dfrac x2$ and $\sin x=2\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2$ to arrive at the simplified expression $f(x)=\cot\dfrac x2$

Answer (score 0):

The OP has asked for a table of values, so here it goes.

[image: table]